# Ruby/Rails: Is it possible to execute a default method when calling an instance (@instance == @instance.all IF "all" is the default method)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

I understand my question is a bit vague but I don't know how else to describe it. I've asked in numerous places and no one seems to understand why I want to do this. But please bear with me, and I'll explain why I want something like this.

I'm using Liquid Templates to allow users to make some dynamic pages on my site. And for those that don't know, Liquid uses a class of theirs called LiquidDrop to expose certain items to the user. Any method in the drop can be called by the Liquid template.

```
class PageDrop < Liquid::Drop
  def initialize(page)
    @page = page
  end

  def name
    @page.name
  end

  def children
    PagesDrop.new(@page.children)
  end
end
```

```
class PagesDrop < Liquid::Drop
  def initialize(pages)
    @pages = pages
  end

  def group_by
    GroupByDrop.new(@pages)
  end

  def all
    @pages.all
  end

  def size
    @pages.size
  end
end
```

For example, I want to be able to do this:

```
@page_drop = PageDrop.new(@page)
@page_drop.children # to get an array of children
```

instead of

```
@page_drop.children.all
```

### Why do I have a pages drop?

Because I want to be able to cleanly split up the methods I can do to an array of pages, and methods I can do to a single page. This allows me to group pages like so:

```
@page_drop.children.group_by.some_method_here_that_the_group_drop_contains
```

To make it simpler for my users, I don't want them to have to think about adding "all" or not to a drop instance to get the "default" object/s that it contains. To reiterate:

```
@pages_drop = PagesDrop.new(Page.all)

@pages_drop == @pages_drop.pages #I want this to be true, as well as
@pages_drop == @pages_drop.all
```

### Where did I get this idea?

In Rails, a scope (association object) (@person.friends) seems to return the array when you do certain things to it: @person.friends.each, for person in @person.friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible. When you write `@instance` you aren't really *calling an instance* as you describe, you're getting a reference to the object that `@instance` refers to.

The reason it seems to work with the collections for Rails' associations is that the the association objects are instances of `Array` that have had some of their methods overridden.

I would consider removing `PagesDrop` and using the `group_by(&:method)` syntax if you want a concise way to express groupings. If you do want to keep it then you can get some way towards what you want by implementing `each` and `[]` on `PagesDrop` and having them delegate to `@pages`. That will let you use `@page_drop.children` in `for` loops, for instance.

Comment: Thanks mikej. Unforunately, the group_by stuff I'm applying to the array are a bit more complicated than that, and I'm not sure how I can put it in that syntax. I think the users will just have to trade a nice chainable syntax for putting .all at the end of sets of objects (like @pages_drop).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to implement has_many outside of rails.  Will the following work?

```
class PageDrop < Liquid::Drop
  attr_accessor :children
  def initialize(page)
    @page = page
    @children = []
  end

  def name
    @page.name
  end
end
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
@page_drop = PageDrop.new(@page)
@page_drop.children.size # => 0
@page_drop.children # => []
```

This also gives you all the standard array functions (group_by, size, each, etc).  If you want to add your own methods, create a class that inherits from Array and add your methods there.

```
class PageArray < Array
   def my_method
     self.each{|a| puts a}
   end
end

class PageDrop < Liquid::Drop
  attr_accessor :children
  def initialize(page)
    @page = page
    @children = PageArray.new
  end
  [...]
end

@page_drop = PageDrop.new(@page)
@page_drop.children.size # => 0
@page_drop.children # => []
@page_drop.children.my_method # Prints all the children
```

Then any functions you don't define in PageArray fall through to the Ruby Array methods.

Comment: Ah... I see what you're trying to do. I'll try it out and see if this will work with Liquid, then I'll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out, and this would have been perfect, if I didn't have named_scopes "exposed" to via the PagesDrop. PagesDrop has a published method that calls @pages.published. This requires @pages to be an association object. It looks like I'll need to require users to put an "all" at the end of every PagesDrop instance, like so: @page_drop.children.all, @page_drop.children.published.all